# Taking data from one array to create another. What's wrong with this loop?

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, loops

I am working on an assignment where I need to create two arrays, then look through them and create a new array that holds any values inside of both the first two. Originally, I was close to accomplishing this by making an arraylist but my lab professor told me that wasn't allowed so I needed to re-start and didn't have enough time to figure out the solution.

If you'd like to see the whole code I have now: http://pastebin.com/thsYnj2z

I am really struggling with this loop here:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < Xarr.length ; i++){
    for(int j = 0 ; j < Yarr.length ; j++)
        //Compare. If the two are the same, they go inside of A.
        if (Xarr[i] == Yarr[j]){
        ArrA[k] = Xarr[i]; 
        k++;
        System.out.println(ArrA[k]);
        break;
}
```

My output is remaining 0 for my ArrA[k] array. I can't seem to trouble shoot this issue on my own.

Comment: First of all, your missing lots of braces. Secondly, why do you break when something the same is found?

Comment: Are you sure you want to increment `k` before you print out `ArrA[k]`?

Comment: @AndrewL. Probably because he has already found a match in both arrays in `Yarr`, so move on to the next index in X. Yarrr matey.

Comment: But breaking will break out of the inner loop. Not sure that's desired

Comment: Why not? its an x^2 algorithm. For each index in X, iterate through Y. If a match is found, add it to the 3rd array and move on to the next index in X.

Comment: @Andraw L. I'm actually not completely positive about the break. I didn't have it there originally but my lab professor told me to add it. There's a huge language barrier. He does not speak English well so it's very hard to understand when he's trying to explain things. I tried a couple times to get him to repeat himself but ended up just putting it there without understanding properly. He was getting very winded and frustrated with me I think.

Comment: @element11 I added it there for test purposes. I thought maybe the output was wacky since it was after that so I wanted to make sure it was increasing. I forgot to add a k output for that test line though. It was to be removed once I got it working.

Comment: @element11 Thank you for the explanation too. That break does make sense if I'm breaking out of the first and going back to the second layer.

Comment: But why would you want to break to the outer loop? Wouldnt that restart the whole algorithm back to the first value of `Xarr`? OP's problem is to derive a 3rd array which is a union of the first two is it not? The only reason the break is there at all is to stop looking through the rest of the array after a match is found, because its not necessary. I can see why the professor told him to put it in there.

Answer (score 1):

try making these changes

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < Xarr.length ; i++){
    for(int j = 0 ; j < Yarr.length ; j++)
        //Compare. If the two are the same, they go inside of A.
        if (Xarr[i] == Yarr[j]){
            ArrA[k] = Xarr[i]; 
            System.out.println(ArrA[k]);  // or print them all later
            k++;
            break;  // break to outer loop 
        }
    }
}
```

**note**

Assuming OP has correctly initialized `ArrA`

**note2**

Assuming that only unique values are required, hence the breaking

Comment: I dont think breaking to the outer loop is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Does your solution require that no values are duplicated in ArrA? Or are duplicate values allowed? For example, if some values occur multiple times in each array, you could get multiple matches on the same number.

If duplicates aren't a problem:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < Xarr.length ; i++){
for(int j = 0 ; j < Yarr.length ; j++){
    //Compare. If the two are the same, they go inside of A.
    if (Xarr[i] == Yarr[j]){
        ArrA[k] = Xarr[i]; 
        System.out.println(ArrA[k]);
        k++;
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, the problem is to take 2 arrays, and produce a third array which is a Union of the first 2. Union of 2 sets being the subset of the values found in both sets.

Your code was missing some braces, so put those back in there. Also you wont want to print the `k+1`th item after you just put a value in `ArrA[k]` im assuming.

Otherwise you were pretty much there. The `break` terminates the inner loop and allows the outer loop to increment `i` and continue on. This is because you have already found a match, no need to continue searching, just move onto the next index in `Xarr`.

Algorithm goes like this: For each value in X, search Y for a match. If it is found, add this value to A.

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < Xarr.length ; i++) {
    for(int j = 0 ; j < Yarr.length ; j++) {
        //Compare. If the two are the same, they go inside of A.
        if (Xarr[i] == Yarr[j]){
            ArrA[k] = Xarr[i]; 
            System.out.println(ArrA[k]);
            k++; //you probably want to increment k after you add to ArrA, not before
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String... args){
    int[] xArr = {1, 1,1,1,1,1};
    int[] yArr = {1, };
    int[] kArr = new int[xArr.length > yArr.length ? xArr.length : yArr.length];


    int k = 0;
    for(int x = 0; x < xArr.length; x++){
        for(int y = 0; y < yArr.length; y ++){
            int xNum = xArr[x];
            int yNum = yArr[y];
            if(xNum == yNum) kArr[k++] = xNum;
        }
    }

    int[] resizedKArr = new int[k];
    for(int i = 0; i < resizedKArr.length; i++) resizedKArr[i] = kArr[i];
    Arrays.sort(resizedKArr);

    for(int x : resizedKArr) System.out.println(x);
}
```

First, xArr and yArr are given some random numbers, and then kArr is initialized with the size of the lagest array we are comparing with to ensure the array has enough space to hold similar values.

Then, in the next section we do a loop inside of a loop to compare the values against each other and if they are similar then k++ and set the next value in the array. This goes on until the loops are completed, notice there really is never a need to break from either loop until all values are compared. At that point the loops break themselves and move on to the next bit of code.

The last section is just to create an array of the same size as k and move the values over, I don't know the requirements of your studies, although when using primitives like this you may want to do this in case you have a matching 0 as a number. Otherwise you'll have a ton of 0s filling the empty spaces of your array.

And lastly, we just sort the array for good measure and print it out.
Hope I've answered your question and you get something out of this post!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is printing ArrA[k] after k++. Try increasing line after print.